# Selecting root id's and leaf id's with leaf data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the structure:

```
question_id | question_prefix | question_location | parent_id | paper_id | answerable
0           | 1               | null              | null      | XXXX-XXX | 0
1           | a               | some/file.ext     | 0         | XXXX-XXX | 1
2           | b               | some/file.ext     | 0         | XXXX-XXX | 0
3           | i               | some/file.ext     | 2         | XXXX-XXX | 1
4           | ii              | some/file.ext     | 2         | XXXX-XXX | 0
5           | 1               | some/file.ext     | 4         | XXXX-XXX | 1
6           | 2               | some/file.ext     | 4         | XXXX-XXX | 1
```

etc...

I need to return a new table in the format

```
lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 | question_id | question_location | paper_id | answerable
1    | a    | null | null | 1           | some/file.ext     | XXXX-XXX | 1
1    | b    | null | null | 2           | some/file.ext     | XXXX-XXX | 0
1    | b    | i    | null | 3           | some/file.ext     | XXXX-XXX | 1
```

etc...

Where 'lvl[x]' is the prefix of the parent in the original table and 1 ~ 4 as there are 4 levels (1-infinity, a-z, i-..., 1-infinity). The list will only include rows where the question_location is not null.

So far I can [*sortof*] return a list of the separated prefixes using the code:

```
SELECT t1.question_prefix as lvl1, t2.question_prefix as lvl2,
    t3.question_prefix as lvl3, t4.question_prefix as lvl4, t4.question_location
FROM question as t1 LEFT JOIN question as t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.question_id
LEFT JOIN question as t3 on t3.parent_id = t2.question_id
LEFT JOIN question as t4 on t4.parent_id = t3.question_id
WHERE t1.question_prefix = "[root number]";
```

The issue with this is it doesn't return root nodes, i.e. if:

```
question_id | question_prefix | question_location | parent_id | paper_id | answerable
10           | 2               | some/file.ext    | null      | XXXX-XXX | 0
```

it won't create the row:

```
lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 | question_id | question_location | paper_id | answerable
2    | null | null | null | 10          | some/file.ext     | XXXX-XXX | 0
```

and if the 'where t1.question_prefix = "1"' clause is removed to enable getting the rest of the questions this happends:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| lvl1 | lvl2 | lvl3 | lvl4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | a    | NULL | NULL |
| 1    | b    | NULL | NULL |
| 1    | c    | i    | NULL |
| 1    | c    | ii   | NULL |
| 1    | c    | iii  | 1    |
| 1    | c    | iii  | 2    |
| a    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| b    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| c    | i    | NULL | NULL |
| c    | ii   | NULL | NULL |
| c    | iii  | 1    | NULL |
| c    | iii  | 2    | NULL |
| i    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| ii   | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| iii  | 1    | NULL | NULL |
| iii  | 2    | NULL | NULL |
| 1    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
```

**The lower '1' will also appear if the 'where t1.question_prefix = "1"' clause is enabled which is something I don't want to happen**

I can also get a list of 'question_id', 'question_location', 'paper_id' and 'answerable' with a basic SELECT command. However, I don't know how to combine the two even if I could get the first part properly working.

Comment: Root node for `question_id = 10` is `| 2    | NULL | NULL | NULL |` (last row in output table) . What's wrong?

Comment: No more `SELECT` needed to combine the `paper_id` and other fields, just add ", t4.paper_id" and each column you need, before `FROM question as t1`

Comment: @MohaMad, that isnt for that question_id, that is for the 6th row down in the last table's lvl4 column, I don't understand why it finds all the leaf nodes of lvl1 then sets lvl1 = all in lvl2 and works it out from there.

the question_id = 10 is not included in the lower table, forexample, if question_id = 0 (first row) had a file url, it would still not show up in the final table.

EDIT: and if I add the t4.paper_location it will only add a paper location to the rows [1, b, ii, 1] and [1, b, ii, 2]

Comment: I can't understand first problem, maybe other rows in `question` table makes conditions TRUE to mentioned row be created! - But second problem mentioned in last comment: Change `t4.paper_id` to `t1.paper_id` to get lvl1's paper_id and other fields in the same way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the join order: `question LEFT JOIN parent LEFT JOIN grandparent LEFT JOIN supergrandparent` ;-)

```
select q4.question_id, q1.question_prefix pr1, q2.question_prefix pr2, q3.question_prefix pr3, q4.question_prefix pr4
from question q4
left join question q3 on q3.question_id = q4.parent_id
left join question q2 on q2.question_id = q3.parent_id
left join question q1 on q1.question_id = q2.parent_id
where q4.question_location is not null
  and '[root_id]' in (q1.question_id, q2.question_id, q3.question_id, q4.question_id)
order by q4.question_id;
```

Note that you cannot use `question_prefix` to identify the root node, because it's not unique in your data. You need to use it's `question_id`.

To get the output as you wish, the SELECT clause is going to be a bit complicated:

```
select q4.question_id, q4.question_location, q4.paper_id, q4.answerable
     , coalesce (q1.question_prefix, q2.question_prefix, q3.question_prefix, q4.question_prefix) lvl1 -- 1st not null value
     , case 
         when q1.question_prefix is not null then q2.question_prefix
         when q2.question_prefix is not null then q3.question_prefix
         when q3.question_prefix is not null then q4.question_prefix
     end lvl2 -- 2nd not null value
     , case 
         when q1.question_prefix is not null then q3.question_prefix
         when q2.question_prefix is not null then q4.question_prefix
     end lvl3 -- 3rd not null value
     , case 
         when q1.question_prefix is not null then q4.question_prefix
     end lvl4 -- 4th not null value
from question q4
left join question q3 on q3.question_id = q4.parent_id
left join question q2 on q2.question_id = q3.parent_id
left join question q1 on q1.question_id = q2.parent_id
where q4.question_location is not null
  and '[root_id]' in (q1.question_id, q2.question_id, q3.question_id, q4.question_id)
order by lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/YHYJ63352

Here is another working query:

```
SELECT t4.question_id, t4.question_location, t4.paper_id, t4.answerable
     , t1.question_prefix as lvl1
     , CASE WHEN t2.question_id <> t1.question_id THEN t2.question_prefix END AS lvl2
     , CASE WHEN t3.question_id <> t2.question_id THEN t3.question_prefix END AS lvl3
     , CASE WHEN t4.question_id <> t3.question_id THEN t4.question_prefix END AS lvl4
FROM question as t1 
JOIN question as t2 ON t2.question_id = t1.question_id OR (t2.parent_id = t1.question_id)
JOIN question as t3 ON t3.question_id = t2.question_id OR (t3.parent_id = t2.question_id AND t2.question_id <> t1.question_id)
JOIN question as t4 ON t4.question_id = t3.question_id OR (t4.parent_id = t3.question_id AND t3.question_id <> t2.question_id)
WHERE t1.question_id = '0'
  AND t2.question_location IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.question_id, t2.question_id, t3.question_id, t4.question_id;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/WJSNZ40178

**Note:** Those queries only work when the nesting depth is limited to 4 levels. If the maximum depth is not fixed, there is no way to solve your issue with one query. You will either need some kind of recursion or change you data structure (e.g. full path or transitive closure).

**Update**

After all - to reduce the complexity i would probabbly do the following: Write four queries (one for each nesting level) and merge them with `UNION ALL`.

```
select q1.*
     , q1.question_prefix as lvl1
     , null as lvl2
     , null as lvl3
     , null as lvl4
from question q1
where q1.parent_id is null
  and q1.question_location is not null

union all

select q2.*
     , q1.question_prefix as lvl1
     , q2.question_prefix as lvl2
     , null as lvl3
     , null as lvl4
from question q1
join question q2 on q2.parent_id = q1.question_id
where q1.parent_id is null
  and q2.question_location is not null

union all

select q3.*
     , q1.question_prefix as lvl1
     , q2.question_prefix as lvl2
     , q3.question_prefix as lvl3
     , null as lvl4
from question q1
join question q2 on q2.parent_id = q1.question_id
join question q3 on q3.parent_id = q2.question_id
where q1.parent_id is null
  and q3.question_location is not null

union all

select q4.*
     , q1.question_prefix as lvl1
     , q2.question_prefix as lvl2
     , q3.question_prefix as lvl3
     , q4.question_prefix as lvl4
from question q1
join question q2 on q2.parent_id = q1.question_id
join question q3 on q3.parent_id = q2.question_id
join question q4 on q4.parent_id = q3.question_id
where q1.parent_id is null
  and q4.question_location is not null

order by lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4
```

Change `where q1.parent_id is null` to `where q1.question_id = [root_id]` if you only need a subtree.

Demos: http://rextester.com/CBV79120 - http://rextester.com/GQBLFS85281

While this query is long and has a lot of code duplication - every part of it is quite simple. It is probably also the fastest one.

Comment: Thank you so much, does basically everything I need! Yeah, thankfully the maximum nesting depth is fixed. My last question is that this still won't return a new row for question '2' even if '2' does indeed have a file path - is this to do with it being on level 1? if so is there a way to fix this? Thanks again, Ryan

Comment: Can you fork one of the demos on rextester to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: http://rextester.com/VZZQ29075

as in do I need to re-run the select statement for each question root?

Comment: The `parent_id` should probably be `0` (not `NULL`): http://rextester.com/TUZR17528

Comment: But '2' is seperate from '1' i.e.

Question 1 has the children a, b, i, ii, part 1, part 2,


Question 2 is a separate from Question 1 - would it make more sense to add a root node and base it off that (so have a place holder root that is only used for referencing the rows

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed - thank you so much you've been a great help.

Comment: Is there a benefit using one over the other? and just ammended slightly so it also checks that t3.question_location IS NOT NULL

Comment: The performance might differ. If that is an issue run both to see which is faster. Otherwise take the one which in your opinion is  less difficult to understand. The fastest query would probably be a huge UNION ALL query.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a self-referencing table question, where your database does not support the `WITH RECURSIVE table_name` clause.

To me, it looks like your joining children with parents rather than parents with children (I could be wrong, though).

If my assumption is true, you would start from the row whose `parent_id` IS NULL.

In my suggested answer, I also put that very condition into the WHERE condition.

Then, I continue with `LEFT JOIN`s, just like you do, but where the child's `parent_id` is the root row's `question_id` and not the other way round.

Finally, I use `COALESCE(lowest_level,medium_level,highest_level)` to make sure that I get the lowermost column values of the remaining columns.

The result is however different from what you would get ...